# Excel VBA AVERAGEIFS range with variables

Tags: vba, excel

I want to put in a variable in the code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").range("P1").Value = _
        "=AVERAGEIFS(B1:B1101, B1:B1101,"">0"",B1:B1101,""<200"")"
```

Some thing like:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").range("P1").Value = _
        "=AVERAGEIFS(B1:B" & MyLastRow & ", B1:B1101,"">0"",B1:B1101,""<200"")"
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: You'll want to use the variable for each of the ranges e.g. `"=AVERAGEIFS(B1:B" & MyLastRow & ",B1:B" & MyLastRow & ","">0"",B1:B" & MyLastRow & ",""<200"")"`

Comment: Your syntax looks correct. As Jordan said, you just need to make sure your average range size matches your criteria range size.

Comment: Sorry. My own syntax is correct. Just a variable name that was wrong